# Can an LLC choose to be taxed as a partnership after electing to be taxed as an s-corp?

Tags: united-states, taxes, limited-liability-company, s-corporation

Once an LLC chooses s-corp status for tax purposes, can they choose say in one years time to be treated as a partnership for tax purposes?

Answer (score 2):

Generally no, unless the initial election was valid since the day of the formation. Otherwise - you'll have to wait for at least 60 months (5 years) before changing a previous election.

See the [IRS form 8832](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f8832.pdf).

There are some special cases when you still can change the election even if the 5 years haven't passed, for example a significant change in ownership (more than 50%). [Here's a nice write-up](https://www.cpa2biz.com/Content/media/PRODUCER_CONTENT/Newsletters/Articles_2014/CorpTax/CheckTheBox.jsp).